# Finding all the groups of an order up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

In general, how does one best approach a question of the form, "Find all the groups of order n up to isomorphism?"

Abelian groups seem to be easier to find.

The first step is factoring out n, but beyond that? Could someone outline a good set of criteria to look at for n or direct me to a good reading?

Comment: I don't think there are many good general tools. You can browse in the groupprops wiki to see discussions for small $n$. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_12https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: A good reading is the article by [Besche, Eick, O'Brian](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBmIW8yOjXAhWO_KQKHaCEDogQFggwMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fera%2F2001-07-01%2FS1079-6762-01-00087-7%2FS1079-6762-01-00087-7.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ZFr4KWLMzJhqhpImyxEyw).

Answer (score 2):

For finite abelian groups, there is indeed a nice classification based on a decomposition of cyclic groups (this is sometimes called the fundamental theorem of abelian groups.

For non-abelian groups, usually the Sylow theorems come to mind.  These theorems allow you to calculate special subgroups of prime power order, based on the prime decomposition of your order $n$.  In special cases, the Sylow theorems give you a complete classification of groups of a particular order.  For example, the theorems can be used to show that any group of order $n = pq$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes, is a (semi-) direct product of cyclic groups.

And while not a "classification," some more advanced topics, such as character theory (representation theory), are used to prove seemingly simple results in finite group theory.  For example, Burnside's $p^aq^b$ lemma is used using characters and --- as far as I know --- the character theory used is the simplest way to prove the result.

You can find the first two results, for sure, in any self-respecting algebra book, such as Artin's *Algebra*, Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, etc.  The last result I mentioned is in Dummit & Foote, I think, if you're interested.